# idiorm/paris - write null to database

Tags: php, mysql, orm, null, idiorm

I'm using Idiorm with Paris for my PHP project.
I want to add some entrys with some null-values to my mysql database.
For Example:

```
$openingtime->setBegin(null);
$openingtime->setEnd(null);
$openingtime->setDayOfWeek(1);
$openingtime->save();
```

The begin- and end-column in database have the type "time" and they are nullable.
The excepted Result

```
+----+-------+------+-----------+
| id | begin | end  | dayOfWeek |
+----+-------+------+-----------+
|  1 | null  | null |         1 |
+----+-------+------+-----------+
```

The result I got:

```
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| id |  begin   |   end    | dayOfWeek |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | 00:00:00 | 00:00:00 |         1 |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

ORM::get_last_query() says something like this:

```
UPDATE `openingtime` SET `begin` = '', `end` = '', `dayOfWeek` = '1'
```

So instead of null, idiorm/paris inserts an empty string.

Is there a possibility to add null instead of an empty string?
Thanks for your Help!

EDIT: 
Classdefinition of OpeningTime added below

```
class OpeningTime extends Model {

    public static $_table     = 'openingtime';
    public static $_id_column = 'id';  

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getDayOfWeek(){
        return $this->dayOfWeek;
    }
    public function getBegin(){
        return $this->begin;
    }
    public function getEnd(){
        return $this->end;
    }

    public function setBegin($begin){
        $this->begin = htmlentities( strip_tags($begin), ENT_QUOTES);
    }
    public function setEnd($end){
        $this->end = htmlentities( strip_tags($end), ENT_QUOTES);
    }
    public function setDayOfWeek($dayOfWeek){
        $this->dayOfWeek = htmlentities( strip_tags($dayOfWeek), ENT_QUOTES);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you also add the `OpeningTime` class definition?

Comment: Hi David, I've added the class definition

Comment: Try to directly use `$openingtime->end = null;` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were the setters, more precisely the functions **htmlentities()** and **strip_tags()** I used in my setters. These functions return an empty String if the given value is null.
My solution now:

```
public function setBegin($begin){
    if(isset($begin)){
        $this->begin = htmlentities( strip_tags($begin), ENT_QUOTES);
    }
    else{
        $this->begin = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks!